# Scenario Status Update

Tags: protractor, cucumber

I'm using cucumber with protractor,
Every time i run my tests, at first it runs check for feature and stepDef files(if all steps are made and stuff), and they all pass, but when it run tests and lets say it can't find some elements, it still has that scenarios status as "passed" in my JSON output file.

Is there a way to update scenario status if there are some errors with tests, either while tests are running or after tests fails, and then I could update JSON file again?

Comment: Look at other stack overflow questions. We don't include tags in titles. That's what *tags* are for.

Comment: This is most likely a problem with how you have written your cucumber scenarios.

Are you doing a return or callback within your steps?

Comment: Not in every step, but i use callbacks. Should i put those in every step?

Comment: Yeah, personally I do returns, but callbacks work too. This will ensure that the steps actually run before passing